# Elementary Row Operations and Row/Column Space Properties

Tags: linear-algebra

There are two facts about elementary row operations and column/row spaces:

1. Column space is affected by elementary row operation, whereas row space is not. (the issue of finding a spanning set of column/row space)
2. Linear dependence relations between columns are preserved over elementary row operations, whereas the same between rows is not. (the issue of finding linear independence between columns/rows)

In finding the column space or row space, we lose and gain something in either case. I am not sure why this is possible intuitively: the issue of finding a span is linked to having linear independence between the vectors. Therefore, my question is a more conceptual one: why are the two above statements intuitively consistent (at least to an amateur like me, they seem opposing)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helpful identity to remember:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
&&&\\
\mathbf{v}_1 & \mathbf{v}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{v}_n \\
&&&\\
\end{array}\right)\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n} = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\mathbf{v}_i.$$
Here, the $\mathbf{v}_i$s are a columns of a matrix, and $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are scalars. In other words, $Ax$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$, where the coefficients are taken from the entries of $x$. For this reason, we know that the range of $x \mapsto Ax$ is simply the columnspace of $A$.

We similarly get $x^\top A$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$. This is because $(x^\top A)^\top = A^\top x$, which is a linear combination of columns of $A^\top$, by the previous argument, which transpose to rows of $A$.

Let's also talk about row operations. Each row operation is represented by an elementary row matrix $E$, which is an invertible matrix we can multiply to the **left** of a matrix in order to perform the corresponding row operation. For example, if we wish to swap the first and second rows of
$$\pmatrix{1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & 6},$$
then we multiply on the left by the matrix:
$$\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}.$$
All elementary row operations correspond to left multiplication by a matrix (which you can find by simply applying the row operations to the identity matrix).

So, why is the rowspace preserved under elementary row operations? Let us suppose $E$ is an elementary row matrix (or indeed, any invertible matrix). We just need to show that $f : x \mapsto x^\top A$ and $g : x \mapsto x^\top EA$ have the same ranges, i.e. $A$ and $EA$ have the same row spaces. Note that
$$g(x) = x^\top EA = (E^\top x)^\top A = f(E^\top x).$$
Immediately, this implies $\operatorname{Range} g \subseteq \operatorname{Range} f$. The reverse implication holds, because $E^\top$ is invertible (since $E$ is), and so
$$g((E^\top)^{-1}x) = f(E^\top(E^\top)^{-1}x) = f(x).$$
So, the ranges of $f$ and $g$ agree, which means that the rowspaces of $A$ and $EA$ agree.

Intuitively, this is just a simple change of variable. The elementary row operations is just "mixing up" the $x^\top$'s we use to generate linear combinations of rows. But we are still multiplying $A$ on the left by all possible $x^\top$'s, so we ultimately get the same rowspaces.

Now, let's look at columns. The claim is, if we apply an elementary row operation $E$ to a matrix, the columns of the matrix maintain the same linear dependencies. That is, if $\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_n$ are the columns of $A$, while $\mathbf{w}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{w}_n$ are the columns of $EA$, and $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are scalars, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_1 \mathbf{v}_1 = 0 \iff \sum_{i=1}^n x_1 \mathbf{w}_1 = 0.$$
Using the identity at the top of this answer, this is equivalent to saying:
$$Ax = 0 \iff EAx = 0$$
for all vectors $x$. But this is true! Obviously $Ax = 0 \implies EAx = 0$, and since $E$ is invertible, we also have $Ax = 0 \implies E^{-1}Ax = 0$, i.e. $EAx = 0 \implies Ax = 0$.

The difference between the results about rows and columns comes from the fact that matrix multiplication is not commutative, and row operations involve left multiplication. This means it will scramble any $x^\top$ we multiply to $A$ on the left, leading to different linear combinations of rows producing the same set of vectors, but when multiplying $x$ on the right, the same null-valued linear combinations of columns will remain null-valued, even after $E$ scrambles the resulting $0$ column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a high-level view.

If you replace a vector in a basis with certain kinds of linear combinations of vectors in the same basis, it doesn't affect the span (but it might affect the entries of the vectors a lot). These are exactly the elementary row/column operations (and why they seem so magically useful). If we do elementary row operations, we don't change the row space, and if we do elementary column operations, we don't change the column space. But, if I do an elementary column operation on a matrix, in almost every case you've done something to the rows that isn't an elementary row operation (so it might affect the span).

For example, look at the matrix below. $$A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 
 \end{array}\right]$$

Let's replace $R_1$ with $R_1+R_2$, an elementary row operation. We get the matrix $$
A'= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 
 \end{array}\right]$$

Notice we didn't do a column operation, since two columns changed (and it wasn't merely a swap). Check for yourself that $\operatorname{Span}\{ (1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,0)\} \neq \operatorname{Span}\{ (2,1,1),(1,1,1),(0,0,0)\}$, so we did change the column span.

But, it turns out you don't change *too* much -- some information is still kept. For example, the dimension of the row space doesn't change when you do elementary column operations, same for the dimension of the column space if you do row operations -- both are the same number, the rank of the matrix.

In the example of $A$ and $A'$ above, the column spans are different, but we can see that in both cases, there are only 2 linearly independent columns (and also two linearly independent rows).